# how to use 24 hour format in date object?

Tags: javascript, datetime, google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

In my example it writes inside calendar hours in 12am-pm format, what should I change? And is it possible to make your own format? For example if I want change `2021-01-27 8:00` to `2021.01.27 8:00`.

```
function myFunction1() {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('callendar id');
      calendar.createEvent("my title",new Date ('2021-01-27 8:00'),new Date ('2021-01-27 13:00'));
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue and your goal. I apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about them, can I ask you about the detail of your current issue and your goal? By this, I would like to try to understand them.

Comment: Regarding `new Date ('2021-01-27 8:00')`, see  [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results), it produces an invalid date in at least one current browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most importantly, dates have no idea what format they are in. It depends on the environment and output settings.

### Configure your environment correctly

#### Specify the correct timezone in the manifest

Your project manifest must be set up for some time. It is important.

[image]

#### Customize the time display in Calendar as you need

You have to remember that dates are not what we see, they are more complex objects of information. What we see are strings from the dates.

[image]

### Let's code

The next code is correct

```
calendar
  .createEvent(
    "my title",
    new Date('2021-01-27 8:00'),
    new Date('2021-01-27 13:00')
  );
```

because there is a correct signature for call `new Date()`

The next code is correct too

```
calendar
  .createEvent(
    "my title2",
    new Date('2021-02-27 8:00'),
    new Date('2021-02-27 8:00')
  );
```

It creates an event with no duration. This is fine. This is logically expected.

To specify the interval you need specify noon time or 24 hour format:

```
calendar
  .createEvent(
    "my title2",
    new Date('2021-02-27 8:00'),
    new Date('2021-02-27 20:00')
  );
```

or

```
calendar
  .createEvent(
    "my title2",
    new Date('2021-02-27 8:00 AM'),
    new Date('2021-02-27 8:00 PM')
  );
```

Usually the duration is simply added to the start time. Like that

```
function createEvent() {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  const start = new Date('2021-02-27 8:00');
  const end = new Date(start);
  end.setHours(end.getHours() + 12);
  calendar
    .createEvent("my title2", start, end);
}
```

Yes, you can use your own formats for creating date:

```
function createEvent() {
  var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
  const start = newDate('27.02.2021 8:00');
  const end = new Date(start);
  end.setHours(end.getHours() + 12);
  calendar
    .createEvent("my title2", start, end);
}

function newDate(string){
  const match = string.match(/(\d{1,2}).(\d{1,2}).(\d{4})\s+(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2})/);
  if(!match) throw new Error('Invalid string');
  return new Date(`${match[3]}-${match[2]}-${match[1]} ${match[4]}`);
}
```